# Best way to store two related Hash Keys for Single value

Tags: performance, perl, memory, hash

I have two Keys for one single value, e.g.

```
( Foo, baa ) -> integer
```

I have to use hashing for the lookup because it is a Big Data issue.

Is the only Way to store the Data in a Hash like

```
Foo -> integer
Baa -> integer
```

?

Furthermore, the relation between the two Keys and the value should not get lost.. e.g. to get or set the related integer value (for Foo and Baa)

Comment: `Because i have to remind the Relation between the two Keys e.g. For get and Set the relaxed integer value (for Foo and baa)`? Was this translated by Google translate or something?

Comment: haha iPad autocomplete sux ;-)

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question so that it makes sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use Data::Alias qw( alias );

my %h = ( Foo => 123 );
alias $h{Baa} = $h{Foo};

$h{Baa} = 456; say $h{Foo};
$h{Foo} = 789; say $h{Baa};
```

But it would be less magical to store a reference.

```
my $s = 123;
my %h = ( Foo => \$s );
$h{Baa} = $h{Foo};

${ $h{Baa} } = 456; say ${ $h{Foo} };
${ $h{Foo} } = 789; say ${ $h{Baa} };
```